# How to resolve debugging error on VS-2019

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I downloaded the Boilerplate template project today. I am able to build without errors and also create a database from the entity model. I have set 'Web.Mvc' project as the startup project.
When i run the application on VS Community 2019 16.4.4 i get the below error. What am i missing here?

Also,  attach to process window does not open from Tools >  Attach to process. I get the same error as in the image.

Error:

```
Unable to start debugging.
Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x8ede000e
```

Build Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I had to re-install VS Community 2019. The previous update corrupted VS2019. Installing V.16.5.4 fix the issue.